# How can I make a table view appear when a button is pressed/tapped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to make a UITableView appear when a user taps on a button and disappear when the button is re-tapped.

I implemented the following code but nothing seems to appear when I tap the button.

```
- (IBAction)dropDown:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
    CGAffineTransform transfrom = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 200);
    self.markersTableView.transform = transfrom;
    self.markersTableView.alpha = self.markersTableView.alpha * (-1) + 1;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

What may potentially be the issue?

EDIT:
I was able to make the UITableView appear and disappear by adding `self.markersTableView.hidden = YES;` in viewDidLoad() and `self.markersTableView.hidden = NO;` in the IBAction method.

However, the table view disappears when I initially tap on the button as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

The fading of the rows is an indication it is moving down the screen, and then it disappears.

It only reappears when I re-tap on the UIButton the 2nd time.

Any clues?

Comment: This is because, according to your recent edit, you initially set it to NOT be hidden, and then set it to HIDDEN on button tap. If you want it to initially be hidden and then appear only on tap, replace the self.markersTableView.hidden values you've posted in the edit above...also, in your button, add an if method that checks for the current self.markersTableView.hidden value, and changes it to the opposite.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I meant I set it to YES on hidden initially and NO on hidden in IBAction...sorry for the confusion, I have edited it now

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a transform on your table view. That will make it LOOK like it's in a different position, but it won't respond to taps correctly.

Instead, use the newer UIView block-based animation methods and change the view's center.

The code might look like this (if you're NOT using auto-layout)

```
[UIView AnimateWithDuration: .2
  animations: ^
  {
    CGPoint center = self.markersTableView.center;
    center.y += 200;
    self.markersTableView.center = center;
  }
];
```

If you're using auto-layout, though, that won't work and you will need to animate the view's position using constraints.

From memory, here's an outline of how to do auto-layout based animations: You would create a vertical position constraint on your table view and connect the constraint to an IBOutlet in your view controller. In your animation code you change the constant of the constraint (the vertical position) and then in the animation block, send the view a needsLayout message.

Comment: I am using auto layout, but I'm not sure I know what you mean. I'm fairly new to iOS programming, can you provide an example? :(

Comment: You just put your animation code inside of the block on the Duncan's code above, instead of using `beginAnimations` and `commitAnimations`.